# File input into arrayList. Same arrayList used to make new objects

Tags: java, arrays, regex, arraylist

I am working on a program where i take input from a file and kick out what i need using a regEx. I kick out integers and strings. one from each line. Each line has info for one object.

```
    try{
        Scanner getAll = new Scanner(new FileReader(eventsFile));

        while(getAll.hasNextLine()){
        fileToArray.add(getAll.nextLine());         
        }

        }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("the file name you entered is not present in the directory");
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("An I/O error present");
    }

    System.out.println(fileToArray.size());
    // we put our regular expression here which kicks out the event 
    //eventPat gets everything after Event= and before ,time
    Pattern eventPat = Pattern.compile("(?<=Event=)(.*)(?=,time)");
    //timePat looks for everynumber from 0-9 whose size is 1 up to 5
    Pattern timePat  = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{1,5}");
```

I then go on to add the int to one array and the string to another.

```
 // this for loop takes the fileToArray which has all the example file contents inside and      matches it for eventPat and adds its findings to an array called typeOfEvents
    for(int i =0 ; i < fileToArray.size(); i++){

    String friskOne = fileToArray.get(i).toString();
    Matcher eventSeeker = eventPat.matcher(friskOne);                     
    while(eventSeeker.find()){
        typeOfEvents.add(eventSeeker.group());
    }
    }

    // this for loop takes the fileToArray which has all the example file contents inside and       matches it for timePat and adds its findings to an array called typeOfTime
    for(int i =0 ; i < fileToArray.size(); i++){

    String frisk =  fileToArray.get(i).toString();
    Matcher timeSeeker = timePat.matcher(frisk);
    while(timeSeeker.find()){
        typeOfTime.add(timeSeeker.group());
    }
    }
```

Then i used a loop where i make the objects. I take the first index of each array and pair them together. Some objects might not be needed as there were no instructions on making them in the file initially.

```
  // here the loop takes the first event in the typeOfEvent array and runs it with the first    
  //this works since everything in , typeOfEvents and typeOfTime is added in the order that it is    //present in the example file. The cast is added 
 //so that the data is changed from object to type long  and string 

public void action()  { 

    for(int i = 0 ; i < typeOfTime.size(); i ++){

        if(String.valueOf(typeOfEvents.get(i))=="WaterOff")
        {Long a = (Long.valueOf((String)typeOfTime.get(i)));
            addEvent(new WaterOff(a));}// Clarification needed does this convert to long from 

        else if ((String)typeOfEvents.get(i)=="WindowMalfunction")
            addEvent(new WindowMalfunction(Long.valueOf((String)typeOfTime.get(i)))); }
```

Error one is that i am getting index out of bounds error. 
Second i think i am not converting the fileinputs to the proper types. i need to make all the strings in the string array into String and all the ints  that i stored in the int array into long as thats what i need to make the object. 
Example 
the file has a line - Event=WaterOff,time=10000
i store waterOff in eventSeeker as WaterOff is an event. I keep 10000 in timeSeeker as its time. I have to later input them to make objects.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this loop:

> ```
> for(int i = 0 ; i < typeOfTime.size(); i ++){
>     if(String.valueOf(typeOfEvents.get(i))=="WaterOff")
> ```

You are iterating until the end of `typeOfTime`,
but accessing elements of a different list, `typeOfEvents`.
The IndexOutOfBoundsException probably happens when the size of `typeOfTime` is bigger than the size of `typeOfEvents`,
so the value of `i` will be beyond the bounds of `typeOfEvents`.
You need to rework the logic to avoid that.

You haven't shared the declarations of `typeOfTime` and `typeOfEvents`.
Try something like this:

```
List<String> typeOfEvents = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Long> typeOfTime = new ArrayList<Long>();
```

To add a `Long` in `typeOfTime`, write like this:

```
typeOfTime.add(Long.parseLong(timeSeeker.group()));
```

#### Code quality issues

Note that you don't need two loops like this:

> ```
> for(int i =0 ; i < fileToArray.size(); i++) {
>     // logic to fill typeOfEvents
> }
> for(int i =0 ; i < fileToArray.size(); i++) {
>     // logic to fill typeOfTime
> }
> ```

You could perform both of those actions in one loop:

```
for(int i =0 ; i < fileToArray.size(); i++) {
    // logic to fill typeOfEvents
    // logic to fill typeOfTime
}
```

Your formatting is terrible. Use your IDE's function to reformat code nice, for example in Eclipse the Control Shift f keyboard shortcut will do that for you.
With the above suggestion applied and the formatting fixed the code would look like this and more readable:

```
    for(int i =0 ; i < fileToArray.size(); i++){
        String frisk = fileToArray.get(i).toString();

        Matcher eventSeeker = eventPat.matcher(frisk);
        while(eventSeeker.find()){
            typeOfEvents.add(eventSeeker.group());
        }

        Matcher timeSeeker = timePat.matcher(frisk);
        while(timeSeeker.find()){
            typeOfTime.add(timeSeeker.group());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are correct. The out of bounds exception IS infact from the error you are pointing out. I shall fix it. 
List<String> typeOfEvents = new ArrayList<String>();
I thought that if i were to give my list a parameter , it would only take that type not change it that type before adding to its self. From my understanding whatever the regex finds and returns are type objects. 
Thank you for the formatting tip. I shall use it from now onwards

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see, the index out of bounds exception may be because you have two patterns one for event and the other one to extract the value of time.

These are two separate patterns, just because the event pattern did not match, does not mean that the time pattern does not match.

Example: Consider the line

> Event_wrong=Hello,time=1000

Here the first pattern does not match, however the second one matches.
Hence you cannot guarantee that the array sizes will be same, hence the index out of bound while iterating.

Suggestions:

- Write a single regex (or do an index of based sub-string)
- In case of a regex, try something like this **"<=Event=(.+?)\;time=(\d+{1,5})"**
- Try debugging or printing out the values from the list after matching the regex

Other suggestion:

- While reading line from the file check the pattern (no need to keep the full file in memory)